# MySQL XAMPP always open a Net Command Pop-up

Tags: mysql, xampp

When I start MySQL on my XAMPP its always ask me "if I allow this app to make a change" by opening a pop up Net Command. If I click yes of course its running. But I dont want to be like that every single time I start MySQL.

[image: This is the administration permission pop up kind of]

I've already search on service.msc and everything about MySQL is set to automatic.

How do I fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change UAC level

Click Show more detail on the pop up
Change...
Then Drag down UAC level

Answer (score 0):

Ref.- https://kb.blackbaud.com/knowledgebase/articles/Article/44890

- Go to Start, select Run...
- Enter msconfig and click OK.
- Switch to the Tools tab.
- Highlight Change UAC Settings and choose Launch.
- Drag the slider-bar down to the bottom level for Never notify.
- Click OK and restart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, following approach helped me

1. Open XAMPP Control Panel
2. Go to "services" listed on the right side
3. Right click on "Apache(version_num)" and then go to "properties"
4. Set "startup type" to "manual" then click on "apply" and "ok".
5. Scroll down & right click on "mysql" and go to "properties".
6. Set "startup type" to "manual" then click on "apply" and "ok".
7. Check by starting apache and mysql again with xampp control panel.